# Excel: 'Unable to set the Calculation property of the Application class'

Tags: excel

I'm trying to automate some stuff in MS Excel. When I try to set the Calculation property I get the following error message: 'Unable to set the Calculation property of the Application class'

I believe this property should be settable.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have an open workbook, ie

```py
import win32com

# Create new Excel instance
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")  

# Open blank workbook
xl.Workbooks.Add()

# Set property
xl.Calculation = win32com.client.constants.xlCalculationManual
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting it to a proper value.

```
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

or one of the following values:

xlCalculationAutomatic: Excel controls recalculation. 
xlCalculationManual: Calculation is done when the user requests it. 
xlCalculationSemiautomatic: Excel controls recalculation but ignores changes in tables.